# Fluent validation: set custom message on custom validation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation, custom-errors

**Scenario**

I have a custom rule to validate the shipping cost of an order:

```
public class OrderValidator : BaseValidator<Order>
{

    private string CustomInfo { get; set; }

    public OrderValidator()
    {
        //here I call the custom validation method and I try to add the CustomInfo string in the message
        RuleFor(order => order.ShippingCost).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure).NotNull().Must(
            (order, shippingCost) => CheckOrderShippingCost(order, shippingCost)
        ).WithMessage("{PropertyName} not set or not correct: {PropertyValue}." + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomInfo) ? "" : " " + CustomInfo));
    }

    //this is the custom validation method
    private bool CheckOrderShippingCost(Order o, decimal shippingCost)
    {
        bool res = false;

        try
        {
            /*
             * check the actual shippingCost and set the res value
             */
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CustomInfo = ex.ToString();
            res = false;
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

In case of exception, I store the exception info into the CustomInfo private member and I add it to the validation message.

Then I run the validator:

```
OrderValidator oVal = new OrderValidator();
oVal.Results = oVal.Validate(order);
if (!oVal.Results.IsValid)
    oVal.Results.Errors.ForEach(delegate(ValidationFailure error) {
        Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorMessage);
    });
```

**Issue**

Everything works right, in case of exception the CustomInfo is properly set to the ex.ToString() value. But eventually the error message displayed in the console does NOT show the CustomInfo, but only the first part of the message:

```
      "Shipping Cost not set or not correct: 5.9"
```

**Question**

Why the custom message does not contains the CustomInfo string?
Is it possible to add the exception info the the custom message in another way?

Answer (score 14):

According to this https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customising&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#CustomError

you should rather use

```
.WithMessage("{PropertyName} not set or not correct: {PropertyValue}. {0}", order => order.CustomInfo);
```

which would require that your CustomInfo on the level of the Order class, rather than your validator class

**EDIT**

You could use:

```
public static class OrderExtensions
{
    private static IDictionary<Order,string> customErrorMessages;

    public static void SetError(this Order order, string message) {
        if (customErrorMessages == null) {
            customErrorMessages = new Dictionary<Order,string>();
        }
        if (customErrorMessages.ContainsKey(order)) {
            customErrorMessages[order] = message;
            return;
        }
        customErrorMessages.Add(order, message);
    }

    public static string GetError(this Order order) {
        if (customErrorMessages == null || !customErrorMessages.ContainsKey(order)) {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        return customErrorMessages[order];
    }
}
```

with some small changes to your validator

```
public class OrderValidator : BaseValidator<Order>
{
    public OrderValidator()
    {
        //here I call the custom validation method and I try to add the CustomInfo string in the message
        RuleFor(order =>     order.ShippingCost).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure).NotNull().Must(
            (order, shippingCost) => CheckOrderShippingCost(order, shippingCost)
        ).WithMessage("{PropertyName} not set or not correct: {PropertyValue}. {0}", order => order.GetError()));
    }

    //this is the custom validation method
    private bool CheckOrderShippingCost(Order o, decimal shippingCost)
    {
        bool res = false;

        try
        {
            /*
             * check the actual shippingCost and set the res value
             */
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            order.SetError(ex.ToString());
            res = false;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point. Though I am not allowed to modify the Order structure. Moreover I think that any validation info should be related to the validator rather than to the validated object.

Comment: You could create a OrderWithInfo class that inherits your order class completely, and make a conversion when you either set, or get the info from the class? Since the rules are defined inside the constructor, it seems quite hard to use anything else but the object that you were validating

Comment: On a side node, if you could add an extension method, that gets the error and sets the error, you wouldn't change anything to your order class, and you could get the error by using `order => order.GetError()`